# How to use Field<T> with Type?

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-dataset

I have a method that determines the min and max of a column in a `DataTable`:

```
public void GetMinMaxRange( DataTable data, string valueColumnName )
{
   var min = data.AsEnumerable().Min(m => m.Field<double>(valueColumnName));
   var max = data.AsEnumerable().Max(m => m.Field<double>(valueColumnName));
}
```

I want to refactor this to be:

```
public void GetMinMaxRange( DataTable data, string valueColumnName )
{
   DataColumn column = data.Columns[valueColumnName];
   var min = data.AsEnumerable().Min(m => m.Field<column.DataType>(valueColumnName));
   var max = data.AsEnumerable().Max(m => m.Field<column.DataType>(valueColumnName));
}
```

I need to determine the datatype and use it instead of hard-coding `m.Field<double>`.  How to do this?

**UPDATE**
As to *why* I want to calculate the difference between the min and the max

```
    public static double/decimal/int GetMinMaxRange<T>(DataTable data, 
          string valueColumnName) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        DataColumn column = data.Columns[valueColumnName];
        var min = data.AsEnumerable().Min(m => m.Field<T>(valueColumnName));
        var max = data.AsEnumerable().Max(m => m.Field<T>(valueColumnName)); ;
        return max - min;
    }
```

Comment: Exactly _why_ do you need it? Try to finish that method, you are not using min/max yet.

Comment: @Henk - updated my question.  Does that make sense?

Comment: You can write that last sample as `public static T GetMinMaxRange<T>(...) ...` which indeed makes sense but needs to spec T at compiletime.

Comment: @Henk - yes, but I can't seem to subtract min from max in this way.

Comment: Which is an entirely different problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply creating this as a generic should work:

```
public void GetMinMaxRange<T>( DataTable data, string valueColumnName ) 
                                                             where T : IComparable<T>
{
   DataColumn column = data.Columns[valueColumnName];
   var min = data.AsEnumerable().Min(m => m.Field<T>(valueColumnName));
   var max = data.AsEnumerable().Max(m => m.Field<T>(valueColumnName));
}
```

Which you would then use as:

```
GetMinMaxRange<MyType>(dataTable, valueColumnName);
```

Comment: I think they're asking for runtime.  This would still be compile time.

Comment: And you will need `where T : IComparable<T>`

Comment: This answers my original question.  I'll ask another one for the subtracting part.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to this on runtime, you can't use generics. You can rewrite your method like this:

```
public void GetMinMaxRangeTest(DataTable data, string valueColumnName)
{
    DataColumn column = data.Columns[valueColumnName];
    var min = data.AsEnumerable().Min(m => Convert.ChangeType(m[valueColumnName], column.DataType));
    var max = data.AsEnumerable().Max(m => Convert.ChangeType(m[valueColumnName], column.DataType));
}
```

I have tested this on a list, like this:

```
List<string> num = new List<string>() { 
    "1", "2", "3", "-1", "11", "10", "100"
};
var min = num.AsEnumerable().Min(m => Convert.ChangeType(m, typeof(int)));
```

and it yields the proper result: -1.

Comment: I get 'Object must implement IConvertible.' error for a DataTable rather than a List

Comment: What type does m[valueColumnName] have? double, decimal, int and string are all IConvertible so m[valueColumnName] having a value of this type can't be the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this so simple. `column.DataType` <strike>will be a SqlDbType and since</strike>     it will only be known at runtime so the compiler can't verify that it is `IComparable`.

Comment: `column.DataType` would return `System.Type` not `SqlDbType` according to my intellisense